# jQuery inquiry .children

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.Name').children(function() {
    var username = $('.Name').text();
    console.log(username);
});
```

I'm curious how I would get this to grab all of the children with the tag 'title' and console.log the value of each of them one by one.

Comment: Can you post the HTML you want to apply this to?

Comment: What do you mean "the tag 'title'" ?

Comment: Something like `$('.Name').children().each(function() { var username = $(this).text(); console.log(username); });` or what?

Comment: Do you mean the title attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `title` is a class (not a tag), and assuming the element is an input (which has a value property):

```
$('.name').children('.title').each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).val() );
});
```

If you meant that `title` is an attribute of an element such as an anchor, try this:

```
$('.name').children('[title]').each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).val() );
});
```

However, an anchor doesn't have a value, so you'd use the `text()` method:

```
console.log( $(this).text() );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.Name > title').each(function() {
    var username = $(this).text();
    console.log(username);
});
```

This will grab all title elements, that are direct children of all elements with class `Name` and runs a function for each of them, logging the text of the titles to the console.

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yqn0L6L/1/)

Comment: Question says `console.log the value of each of them one by one`, then why are you showing text?

Comment: Since when is `title` an element that may occur more than once, and in the body of a document?

Comment: @isherwood it is possible, just try it out. Though i don't really see any sense in it

Comment: @Apul Gupta I don't really get your question. I am logging the text of the titles to the console, as wished

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.name > title').each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```